AoS with () Access instead of [] Access without Performance loose?
preliminary remark: The code I use in this post is not that short. I am aware of the guideline to use a Minimal, Reproducible Example. However in that case there is not that much that can be reduced, since I am comparing the Performance of two different Versions and have to define the datalayout, allocate and initialize fields and measure the performance of both versions.
Consider you have an DataLayout like this:
struct  C_AoS {
    double comp1, comp2;
};

struct ElementAoSstruct {
    C_AoS *firstVector;
    C_AoS *secondVector;
};

And you would allocate memory for n Elements and for the length (here nDof) of the first and second vector and initialize the vectors with some values:
ElementAoSstruct *ElementAoS = (ElementAoSstruct*) malloc(sizeof(ElementAoSstruct) * n_Elements);
for (size_t i = 0; i < n_Elements; ++i) {
    ElementAoS[i].firstVector = (C_AoS*) malloc(sizeof(C_AoS) * nDof * 2);
    ElementAoS[i].secondVector = &ElementAoS->firstVector[nDof];

    for (size_t j = 0; j < nDof * sizeof(C_AoS) / sizeof(double); j++) { ((double *) ElementAoS[i].firstVector)[j] = j; }
    for (size_t j = 0; j < nDof * sizeof(C_AoS) / sizeof(double); j++) { ((double *) ElementAoS[i].secondVector)[j] = j+0.2; }
}

you would result in an standard AoS Access pattern: for Example: ElementAoS[someIndex].firstVector[anotherIndex].comp1
Now I want to change the Access Pattern to ElementAoS[someIndex].firstVector(anotherIndex).comp1
I thought that this should be straight forward with c++ operator overloading, by just adding a new Layer between C_AoS and ElementAoSstruct ( I gave it some other name for comparison)
struct AoS_Container {
    C_AoS *_buffer;
    __attribute__((always_inline)) C_AoS& operator()(size_t index) const {
        return _buffer[index]; }
};

struct Element_AoS_OperatorOverload {
    AoS_Container firstVector;
    AoS_Container secondVector; };

And this actually works. However if I compare the Performance of both Versions I am getting about 20 - 30 % Performance loose with the operator overloading version. This is the full code I use to measure the performance:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

struct  C_AoS {
    double comp1, comp2;
};

struct ElementAoSstruct {
    C_AoS *firstVector;
    C_AoS *secondVector;
};

struct AoS_Container {
    C_AoS *_buffer;
    __attribute__((always_inline)) C_AoS& operator()(size_t index) const {
        return _buffer[index];
    }
};

struct Element_AoS_OperatorOverload {
    AoS_Container firstVector;
    AoS_Container secondVector;
};

void printTime(std::string text, std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> start, std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> end) {
    const std::chrono::duration<double> elapsedTime( end - start );
    const double seconds( elapsedTime.count() );
    std::cout << text << seconds << "s\n\n";
}

template <typename T>
static void someKernal (T &__restrict firstVector, const T &__restrict secondVector, const size_t length) {

    const double factor = 1.1;
    for (size_t i{}; i < length; i++) {

        firstVector[i].comp1  += - factor * secondVector[i].comp1 ;
        firstVector[i].comp2  += - factor * secondVector[i].comp2;
    }
}

template <typename T>
static void someKernalParentheses (T &__restrict firstVector, const T &__restrict secondVector, const size_t length) {

    const double factor = 1.1;
    for (size_t i{}; i < length; i++) {

        firstVector(i).comp1  += - factor * secondVector(i).comp1 ;
        firstVector(i).comp2  += - factor * secondVector(i).comp2;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int n_Elements = 2500000;
    if (argc >= 2) { n_Elements = atoi(argv[1]) * 1000; }

    int const nDof = 64;

    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> start, end;

    ElementAoSstruct *ElementAoS = (ElementAoSstruct*) malloc(sizeof(ElementAoSstruct) * n_Elements);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_Elements; ++i) {
        ElementAoS[i].firstVector = (C_AoS*) malloc(sizeof(C_AoS) * nDof * 2);
        ElementAoS[i].secondVector = &ElementAoS->firstVector[nDof];

        for (size_t j = 0; j < nDof * sizeof(C_AoS) / sizeof(double); j++) { ((double *) ElementAoS[i].firstVector)[j] = j; }
        for (size_t j = 0; j < nDof * sizeof(C_AoS) / sizeof(double); j++) { ((double *) ElementAoS[i].secondVector)[j] = j+0.2; }
    }

    Element_AoS_OperatorOverload *ElementAoS_OperatorOverload = (Element_AoS_OperatorOverload*) malloc(sizeof(Element_AoS_OperatorOverload) * n_Elements);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_Elements; ++i) {
        ElementAoS_OperatorOverload[i].firstVector._buffer = (C_AoS*) malloc(sizeof(C_AoS) * nDof * 2);
        ElementAoS_OperatorOverload[i].secondVector._buffer = &ElementAoS_OperatorOverload[i].firstVector._buffer[nDof];

        for (size_t j = 0; j < nDof * sizeof(C_AoS) / sizeof(double); j++) { ((double *) ElementAoS_OperatorOverload[i].firstVector._buffer)[j] = j; }
        for (size_t j = 0; j < nDof * sizeof(C_AoS) / sizeof(double); j++) { ((double *) ElementAoS_OperatorOverload[i].secondVector._buffer)[j] = j+0.2; }
    }
    
    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < n_Elements ; i++) {
        someKernal(ElementAoS[i].firstVector, ElementAoS[i].secondVector, nDof);
    }
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    printTime("Runetime AoS Struct", start, end);

    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < n_Elements ; i++) {
        someKernalParentheses(ElementAoS_OperatorOverload[i].firstVector, ElementAoS_OperatorOverload[i].secondVector, nDof);
    }
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    printTime("Runetime AoS Operator Overload()", start, end);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_Elements; ++i) {
        free(ElementAoS[i].firstVector);
        free(ElementAoS_OperatorOverload[i].firstVector._buffer);
    }
    free(ElementAoS);
    free(ElementAoS_OperatorOverload);

    return 0;
}

What I know is that it is not the fault of the operator overloading. If I call someKernal with ElementAoS_OperatorOverload[i].firstVector._buffer and second vector accordingly I would get the same performance penalty. So the performance penalty might be caused from the layer inbetween, however since I have to do the operator overloading in that layer I don't see to get rid of it. Do you see any chance to change the Access pattern to the one with the Parentheses and still have the same Runtime?
I used the gcc 10.2.1 compiler with -Ofast -march=native compiler flags.

Side note: using malloc/free in C++ is a huge code smell and often a big source of bugs. Also, the -Ofast flag is dangerous and can lead to incorrectly behaving programs.

I don't see a 20% slowdown with similar settings (godbolt times out for larger n_Elements). With gcc (trunk) the performance flips

N.b. your casts (double *) ElementAoS[i].firstVector are strictly undefined behaviour. Only std::complex is allowed to be treated like that.
